# How can I do this transformation?

Tags: matrices

I have this equation:$$D=LRL^{H}$$
where D is diagonal matrix, L is lower triangular matrix, R is positive definite matrix.
How can one obtain these equations from above equation?$$R^{-1}=L^{H}D^{-1}L$$
$$R^{-1}=(D^{\frac{-1}{2}}L)^{H}(D^{\frac{-1}{2}}L)$$

Comment: What is $H$? in the equations?

Comment: H is hermitian form of matrix

Comment: Not hermitian form: hermitian transpose, also called conjugate transpose, Hermitian conjugate, etc.

Comment: Can you use $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ and $(AB)^H=B^HA^H$? I should think your formulas would follow from those.

Comment: yes, I can use these properties, but how can I apply them?

Comment: Also you need $L$ to be invertible (which is not automatically true) in order for $D^{-1}$ to exist.  If it is invertible, $D$ is positive definite and $D^{-1/2}$ exists (just take the $-1/2$ power of each diagonal element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $L$ is invertible, so is $L^H$.  Take the inverse of both sides of your equation, noting that the inverse of a product of invertible matrices is the product of the inverses in reverse order:

$$ D^{-1} = (L R L^H)^{-1} = (L^H)^{-1} R^{-1} L^{-1}$$

Now can you see how to get $L^H D^{-1} L$ on the left side?

Comment: Thank you! Could you please introduce me a good reference for these properties of matrix?

Comment: @hoka: any good linear algebra book ought to do you well.